# D3.js - How to create transitions with drop down control for donut chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I want to create a donut chart with d3.js that changes with drop down options.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>


  <form id="form1">
    <select id="thedropdown">
      <option value ="data">Loesche</option>
      <option value ="data1">Bayer</option>
      </select>
    </form>


<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
```

This is the first part of my code I wrote. The drop down options are shown, but don't work.

```
<script>

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var width = 450
    height = 450
    margin = 40

var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - margin

var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var data = {a: 785, b: 345, c: 98}
var data1 = {a: 116998, b: 39586, c: 90 }

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(data)
  .range(["#003f5c", "#bc5090", "#ffa600"])

var pie = d3.pie()
  .value(function(d) {return d.value; })
var data_ready = pie(d3.entries(data))


document.getElementById("form1").onchange = function() {
  company = document.getElementById("thedropdown").value;
  if(company == "data") {
data = [785, 345, 98];
draw();
}

if(company == "data1") {
mydata = [116998, 39586, 90];
draw();
}
}

svg
  .selectAll('whatever')
  .data(data_ready)
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(100)         // This is the size of the donut hole
    .outerRadius(radius)
  )
  .attr('fill', function(d){ return(color(d.data.key)) })
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .style("stroke-width", "2px")
  .style("opacity", 0.7)


</script>
```

What is the best technique to to solve this problem? What have I done wrong by creating the drop down? I would like to use a drop down option selector because I have around 20 categories and I would look not good with a click button option.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `draw()` function that your are not showing? Otherwise, this is a brief example on using a dropdown to change dots on a scatter plot (https://observablehq.com/@kickout/basic-scatterplot)

```
  dropdown.on('change',function(d){
    var selvalue = this.value      
    updateColor(selvalue)
```

Comment: No, I don't have this function. This is my whole code.

Comment: I have the draw command here `document.getElementById("form1").onchange = function() {
  company = document.getElementById("thedropdown").value;
  if(company == "data") {
data = [785, 345, 98];
draw();`